# How do I get the 'Nightmare' achievements during the halloween event?

Tags: achievements, payday-2

There are some achievements at the new Payday 2 halloween update and I was wondering how to get them.
I mean these achievements:

[image]

There are:

- First Nightmare
- Second Nightmare
- Third Nightmare
- Fourth Nightmare
- Fifth Nightmare

I randomly got the First nightmare, but I was wondering what to do to get these achievements?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

need to get at least 3 baby masks on the upstairs after cracking the safe open. Each difficulty level gives you an achievement. Need to do all 4 of course to get all 4. Masks are in random spots. Sometimes grabbing one triggers a witch that will instant down you so u need to have support to get you up.

Comment: I got the achievement after one mask on Overkill, after 6(!) masks on Normal.  So it looks like you need to grab the right mask, not a set number of them.

Answer (score 1):

Just finish the level on every difficult and get all the baby's masks.

Answer (score 0):

you can get third nightmare by getting all the baby masks on the ground floor of the safe house only on very hard mode and have to open vault first to get to ground floor

Comment: Ok this is a part of the full answer.